# Forward slash in the ios app product name

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to have a forward slash character in the app name? I tried setting it to "my/app" and it crashes on launch:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire error?

Comment: Since the product name is used for file names, no. You can have a slash in the name shown under the icon or in the name shown in iTunes, but not in the product name used in Xcode.

Comment: thanks @rmaddy, changing the name under the icon is what I wanted

Comment: Just change the Display Name in Info.plist for that.